# i tried an html program for checking validation for empty field but it does't working?

Tags: html, validation, notnull

i tried an html program for checking validation for empty field but it does't working?
please help me to show what is the error in my code?
the code snippet is below..

i tried an html program for checking validation for empty field but it does't working?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<style>
body
{
    padding: 10px;
    font-family:Calibri;
    font-size:12pt;
}

td
{
    padding:5px;
}
input
{
    font-family:Calibri;
    font-size:12pt;
}

span
{
    font-family:Calibri;
    font-size:9pt;
    color:red;
}

</style>    

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
  <table>
<tr>
    <td>First Name:
    </td>
    <td><input type='text' id='txtFName' class="required"/ >
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Last Name:
    </td>
    <td><input type='text' id='txtLName' class="required"/ >
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Age:
    </td>
    <td><input type='text' id='txtAge'/ >
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email:
    </td>
    <td><input type='text' id='txtEmail' class="required"/ >
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style='text-align:center;'><input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value=" Submit ">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

  </body>

</html>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function(e)
     {
     alert("hai");
        var isValid = true;
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
            if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                isValid = false;
                $(this).css({
                    "border": "1px solid red",
                    "background": "#FFCECE"
                });
            }
            else {
                $(this).css({
                    "border": "",
                    "background": ""
                });
            }
        });
        if (isValid == false) 
            e.preventDefault();
        else 
            alert('Thank you for submitting');
    });
}); 
    </script>
```

Comment: Why don't you try jQuery validation plugin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the Jquery library first before the plugin, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yxex7717/).

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include jQuery library in your head tag and try.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Include your validation script at the bottom of the page.

Comment: is it in between <body> and <html>?

Answer (score -1):

Web application frameworks and tools are becoming smarter day by day, if the web-developers-community needs a change in framework/tools which is widely accepted and common, it gets adopted and rolled out, and all such tools have become so much web-developer's friendly today, specially Rails, jQuery etc, now you just need to google your wish, and you  will find some plug-able, minimum setup/config libraries waiting for you to try out :)

So in this case just google for html form inputs validations.

Comment: the above is tried with help of google. but i can't able to fix the problem.. i am a beginer in html